# Google Maps API v3: Markers not being removed

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm creating a map that loads & destroys markers based on both the bounding box and zoom level. I'm having a real problem getting markers to properly be removed, it seems to work sometimes for certain situations.

I have an object that contains the marker info, which also contains the google maps marker object. My code detects if the market should be deleted based on the bounding box or zoom-level. I set the marker object to "setMap(null);" and using firebug I can see that its being set, I then remove the parent object entirely and the objects data length is updated properly.

I output to the firebug console when a marker is supposedly deleted, seems to be working and I can see that the marker isn't being re-crated from the ajax call for markers on the boundingbox change.

Yet if I zoom around the map I can sometimes see that the markers are being removed, if I zoom away then pan back holding the mouse down. Or sometimes the markers will all be removed if I zoomout the first time, but if I zoom in again then back out they are not removed.

I must be doing something wrong with the logic of my code, I'm stumped.

You can view the source of 
http://www.trailforks.com/map/test.php?lat=49.352247&lon=-123.202413
the JS is
http://www.trailforks.com/map/includes/map.js

the code for deleting a marker is at the bottom

```
function clearMarkerMemory(mapItem, i) {
  google.maps.event.removeListener(mapItem.lis);    // remove stored listener

  mapper.data[i].obj.setMap(null); // remove marker
  mapper.data.splice(i, 1);

  console.log("removed marker "+mapItem.icon+":"+mapItem.nid+' '+mapItem.name);
};
```

I added some more debug into to the console, going to a simple area of the map with only 2 markers http://www.trailforks.com/map/test.php?lat=49.43210641783767&lon=-123.49878636730955&z=14

I can see the markers created, then move the map a bit and see that the markers weren't re-created because they were detected in the marker object. I then move the viewport so one of the markers is off the screen and I can see that the marker is removed and the marker object length updates. But if I pan the map back over the marker is still on the map.

[image]

Comment: I am having difficulties reproducing the "bug" if bug there actually is. Had a look at your code and it's well written and AFAICS you're doing the right thing. Not that it should matter, but have you tried setting the whole `data[i]` object to `null` before splicing it out of the array?

Comment: +1 for a well-written, intelligent question, BTW...

Comment: To reproduce goto this viewpoint http://www.trailforks.com/map/test.php?lat=49.344530719060245&lon=-123.1294569147949&z=13 then clickdrag the mouse so all the yellow markers on the left are off the screen. then drag the map back in that direction holding down the mouse, so the ajax call of markers doesn't fire yet, you will see all the markers have been deleted. But then zoom in once and out and try it again and it will most likely be broken, the markers will remain 100% of the time now. Even though they are removed from the mapper.data object.

Comment: I tried adding "mapper.data[i] = null;" but had no effect.

Comment: I still haven't figured out why this is happening or another way to go about it.

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling with similar problem for a long while until I realized that the map marker's setMap-method is asynchronous. When you call that and immediately remove any references to that marker object, the browser's garbage collector steps in and cleans it up from the memory and thus prevents the actual remove operation from happening.

Try it out by just commenting out the line with the splice call and see if that helps. If it does help, you should consider delaying the removal of the object, or alternatively storing the reference to the marker object until it's really removed. How to detect if it's really removed? I have no idea.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {  refreshMarkers(); }); //refresh markers when user moves map
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {  refreshMarkers(); }); //refresh markers when user moves map
```

change it to:

**EDIT, (after comments):**

To prevent multiple instances of the event handler occurring simultaneously, a global variable could be used, as follows:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {  
if (processing) { // var processing is global
    return;
}
processing = true;
refreshMarkers(); 
processing = false;

}); //refresh markers when user moves map
```

That should cover both situations. As it is now, with two different event listeners, the AJAX calls could be conflicting, and you maybe firing a second call before the first one has completed.

Comment: the problem with using "bounds_changed" is it starts calling a TON of the ajax calls for every little movement of the mouse, this could equal hundreds by the time the user lets go of the mouse, "dragend". But i've tried it anyway and the problem still persists, if I pan around loading a unch of markers then zoom out, none of the markers are removed even with the single listener. I have also tested with just enabling either dragend or zoom_changed.

Comment: That is easily prevented with a global variable that indicates that an event is being processed. (See the edit to my reply).

Comment: the above code still doens't work, it never seems to be true, and i get a tone of aborted POST's in the firebug console, the map is super laggy. It would be nice to have just one listener, but I'm fairly certain my problem with markers not deleting is not related to having multiple listeners since I can product the problem with only 1 listener enabled.